# Defining Multiple (similar) relationships between two models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration, associations

I've been trying permutations of other (very) similar answers here on SO but haven't gotten this to click and I feel like I'm close.

I'd like to relate a Users model to a Category model in two different ways depending on which notification channel (either text or email) the user wants for each Category. Users can have many categories, and vice versa.

Desired outcome:

`>>@user.textcategories` => `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>` of Categories.

`>> @user.emailcategories` => `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>` of Categories.

`>> @user.emailcategories << Category.first`

`>> @user.textcategories << Category.third` etc.

Current Code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :emailcategories 
  has_many :categories, through: :emailcategories

  has_many :textcategories
  has_many :categories, through: :textcategories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :emailcategories 
  has_many :users, through: :emailcategories

  has_many :textcategories 
  has_many :users, through: :textcategories
end

class Emailcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
end

class Textcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
end
```

The migration/schema:

```
create_table "emailcategories" do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :category_id
      t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
      t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
    end

    create_table "textcategories" do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :category_id
      t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
      t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
    end

    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
    end

    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.string :name
    end
```

The current error message: 
`>> @user.emailcategories << Category.first`
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Emailcategory(#70239513207200) expected, got Category(#70239513077640)

Github to clone and try: https://github.com/Grantimus9/TestRels

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above answer is correct with regards to your existing code. However, if you want to use the `<<` syntax, you should use STI on the join table. (I also think this is a somewhat cleaner solution although that may be personal preference.)

```
# db/schema.rb
create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "category_users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "category_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.string   "type"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :email_category_users
  has_many :email_categories, through: :email_category_users, source: :category
  has_many :text_category_users
  has_many :text_categories, through: :text_category_users, source: :category

  # If you also need to get all categories on a user
  has_many :category_users
  has_many :categories, through: :category_users
end

# app/models/category_user.rb
class CategoryUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
end

# app/models/email_category_user.rb
class EmailCategoryUser < CategoryUser
end

# app/models/text_category_user.rb
class TextCategoryUser < CategoryUser
end

# app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_users 
  has_many :users, through: :category_users
end
```

This solution lets you use all of the syntax outlined in the OP for creating/accessing categories (although it's `@user.text_categories` etc., note the underscore)

Comment: This is the way to go - it allows me to easily add new relationships between the two models in the future by extending Category just like how EmailCategoryUser extends CategoryUser.

Answer (score 0):

You did it incorrectly. You should do as below :

```
@user.emailcategories.create! category: Category.first
@user.textcategories.create! category: Category.third
```